# Append is only appending last row

Tags: python, pandas, append

I am trying to append all the row after i scrape data from the website. But for some reason it 
 only appends the last row. Below is my code that i wrote to append the values

```
columns = ['Manager ID','Defect Count','Transactions','DPMO']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= columns)

for i in range(0,len(rows)):
tds = rows[i].find_all('td')
if len(tds) == 4:
    values = [tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text]
else:
    values = [td.text for td in tds]

df1 = df.append(pd.Series(values,index= columns),ignore_index = True)
print(df1)
```

Sample data i am trying to append after scrape are

```
 ['jerejn', '0', '6', '0']
 ['asaeabe', '74', '209', '261,484']
 ['efseu', '5', '185', '26,316']
 ['fddes', '0', '1,534', '0']
```

But my output looks like this.Only the last row.Any help on how to make this work is appreciated

```
 Manager ID Defect Count Transactions DPMO
0    fddes            0        1,534    0
```

Comment: Your code is producing an error.  What is `rows`

Comment: I got rows from  rows = table.find_all('tr')
Sample rows are        [<tr>
<td>jerejn</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td>asaeabe</td>
<td>74</td>
<td>209</td>
<td>261,484</td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td>efseu</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>185</td>
<td>26,316</td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td>fddes</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1534</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>]

Comment: Of course you get this problem. Your code overwrites the variable 'values' instead of saving them as a list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forgot your indents.
Try this please. If dont working add some rows for a mini-example so we can try it ;)

```
columns = ['Manager ID','Defect Count','Transactions','DPMO']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= columns)

for i in range(0,len(rows)):
    tds = rows[i].find_all('td')
    if len(tds) == 4:
        values = [tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text]
    else:
        values = [td.text for td in tds]

    df1 = df.append(pd.Series(values,index= columns),ignore_index = True)
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending to `df1`, I think you should append to `df`, i.e.

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(values,index= columns),ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: I used df first but didn't worked, but all of the sudden it worked with df. May be my indents was incorrect. I fixed the indents suggested by @credenco and changed df1 to df and it worked fine